# What character encoding or file format does NSKeyedArchiver use?

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I am currently investigating a crash during unarchiving of a file supposedly stored through `NSKeyedArchiver`. The crash log contains the first 8 byte quartets of the file (I only included the first 2 below).

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0xffffffa6, 0xffffff9e, ...)
```

I have been unable to decode these bytes into anything useful using ASCII, Base64, UTF8 or UTF16. Does anyone know what kind of file format and/or character encoding `NSKeyedArchiver` uses or how I could decode these bytes to something human readable?

Comment: Perhaps the fact that you can't decode it into anything sensible is precisely because it's corrupted.

Comment: @Avi Yes, that could be correct. It's just weird that the only way the file is written is through an `NSKeyedArchiver` - at least as far as I can see. Hence, I was hoping there was a way to manually decode an archive into something human readable.

Comment: It might a binary plist.

Comment: It is indeed a binary plist.  You can use `plutil -p` on your archive file.  There are also other options to check the integrity.

Comment: @Avi Thank you. Unfortunately, the `plutil` command doesn't seem to be able to generate a human-readable format from just the start of the file. I only have the first few bytes as the crash log is from Fabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyed archives are stored as binary plists.  You can use the `plutil` command line utility to print, verify or manipulate the contents.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the `plutil` command doesn't seem to be able to generate a human-readable format from just the start of the file. I only have the first few bytes as the crash log is from Fabric.

Comment: That really says that it's simply corrupt, hence the crash.  A strange situation, to be sure.

Comment: I'll give you the accepted answer since I asked for the file format. A pity that `plutil` doesn't help me in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: plutil is only the first step to convert the binary into xml. you then can run the data value (only) through a base64 decoder to try to extract some of the info.. but you'll have to search through the output a bit to be able to piece any relevant info